# Huggingface - Inference code in trainer script

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, amazon-sagemaker, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I want to train a model for token classification using **Huggingface Trainer** and deploy it as an **AWS Sagemaker** endpoint. I followed [this](https://github.com/NielsRogge/Transformers-Tutorials/blob/master/LayoutLMv3/Fine_tune_LayoutLMv3_on_FUNSD_(HuggingFace_Trainer).ipynb) link and I am able to train and deploy the model using Huggingface estimator. Below is my code -

```
# create the Estimator
huggingface_estimator = HuggingFace(
    entry_point='train.py',
    source_dir='./code', 
    ...)

# train the model
huggingface_estimator.fit()

# create the endpoint prediction
predictor = huggingface_estimator.deploy(...)

# evaluate the model
predictor.predict(#data#)
```

How do I pass prediction input (*in this case data*). And also, what is the input data structure expected by the predict method()? Can someone point me to the documentation for adding the inference code in the train.py file? The model I am working with expects an *image, words, bounding boxes*.

Answer (score 0):

For images you can pass the data as bytes and you will have to write a custom inference.py file which overloads model_fn and predict_fn to handle the model load and prediction logic. Please refer below example
https://github.com/huggingface/notebooks/blob/main/sagemaker/17_custom_inference_script/code/inference.py

Comment: +1 for _that_ specific notebook!! seems to be the most comprehensive guide I've found on custom inference for the SageMaker Hugging Face integration.